# redhat mysql failure

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

```
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 15:42:40 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 '#'rpm -qa | grep mysql

    mysql-server-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
    mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.5r1144-7.el6.x86_64
    mysql-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
    mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
    qt-mysql-4.6.2-17.el6.x86_64
```

I try `chmod` and `chown` to `'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'`
and I have a symbloic link with `/tmp/mysql.sock`.

when I start Mysql, it states:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (40)

I try  both `mysql` and `mysqld`:

```
 service mysql status
```

It returned.

I also can't start mysql my `/etc/init.d/mysql start` and `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`

> /etc/init.d/mysql start
>     -bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory
>
> mysql: unrecognized service

please help!

Comment: Specify your problem  in question insted of 'redhat mysql failuar,'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I needed to install `php` ,`mysql`, `mysqld` and `php-mysql` packages.

Answer (score 0):

`Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead Package MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

It looks like you downloaded the MySQL-server package from the homepage and installed with rpm -ivh. Verify with:

`$ rpm -qa | grep MySQL`

If you want to install mysql-server from the repository (base, epel, ...), you must uninstall the MySQL-server first by executing:

`# yum remove MySQL-*`

Then

`# yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel`

The init script from *MySQL-server* package is **mysql** instead of **mysqld** from mysql-server. The hint for you is type some characters (/etc/init.d/mysq) and press *Tab or Tab Tab*.